# In the second time that I call this function the program stops working

Tags: java, javafx, awt

In my application I have a button that calls the function below when clicked. When I click once, firefox  is opened normally with my html file, but if I click again the program stops working. I tested closing firefox before clicking again, but the program still crashes.

If I set chrome as my default browser and click in the button this message appears in my IDE:

```
"ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment."
```

However the HTML file is opened normally, but if I click again it crashes. Obs: if firefox is my default browser the IDE doesn't show any messages.
(I'm using IntelliJ, java version is 10).

So what should I do to be able to click more than 1 time?

```
@FXML
public void showListOnBrowser () {

    File htmlFile = new File(dir.getPath() + "/" + Main.usuario.getName() + ".html");

    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Desktop is an AWT class, not JavaFX - might want to change the tags for information.

Comment: "Crashes" how? Do you get an `Exception`?

Comment: @Zephyr I get no exceptions the application becomes gray and the system ask if i want to force quit like this: https://prnt.sc/k267jg

Comment: @purringpigeon  thanks, I will change it.

Comment: Sorry for being a retarded,  this answer solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34429067/10027833